# Expected value of the expression $3 □ 3 □ 3 □ ⋯ □ 3 □ 3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, expected-value

Let $p = 2017$ be a prime number. Let $E$ be the expected value of the expression
$3
□
3
□
3
□
⋯
□
3
□
3$
where there are
$p
+
3$
threes and
$p
+
2$
boxes, and one of the four arithmetic operations
{
+
,
−
,
×
,
÷
}
is uniformly chosen at random to replace each of the boxes. If
$E
=
\frac{m}{n}$
, where
$m$
and
$n$
are relatively prime positive integers, find the remainder when
$m
+
n$
is divided by
$p$
.

It's a question from https://gonitzoggo.com/archive/problem/431/english
Recently, I've been taking preparation for junior Math Olympiad Contest and found this problem.

I've tried many combinations of arithmetic operations to find the value of $E $  but ended up each time getting a new value which doesn't match with the answer. How can I get the exact value of $E$ ?

Comment: Is $3+3×3$ understood to mean $18$ or $12$?

Comment: Follow the order of operations (PEMDAS, or "Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally"), i.e., do multiplication and division from left to right before doing addition and subtraction from left to right.

Comment: Using BODMAS , it should be $12$ I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Partial answer

It may be easier to start with smaller versions of the problem, and see if we can find a pattern.

When there is only one operator box, with two operands, there are four possible expression values:

- $3 + 3 = 6$
- $3 - 3 = 0$
- $3 \times 3 = 9$
- $3 \div 3 = 1$

So $E = 4$.

With more operators, let's get help from our computer.

```
from fractions import *

# Use Fraction arithmetic to avoid floating-point errors.
F3 = Fraction(3)

OPERATORS = ['+', '-', '*', '/']

def generate_expressions(num_operators):
    if num_operators == 0:
        yield 'F3'
    else:
        for rec in generate_expressions(num_operators - 1):
            for op in OPERATORS:
                yield rec + op + 'F3'

def E(num_operators):
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for ex in generate_expressions(num_operators):
        total += eval(ex)
        count += 1
    return total / count
```

With this brute-force approach, I get:

- $E(0) = 3$
- $E(1) = 4$
- $E(2) = \frac{29}{6}$
- $E(3) = \frac{199}{36}$
- $E(4) = \frac{1319}{216}$
- $E(5) = \frac{8539}{1296}$
- $E(6) = \frac{54359}{7776}$
- $E(7) = \frac{341779}{46656}$
- $E(8) = \frac{2128799}{279936}$
- $E(9) = \frac{13163419}{1679616}$
- $E(10) = \frac{80933639}{10077696}$

After this point, the $O(4^n)$ running time of this naïve algorithm becomes unbearable, so I'll stop there.

But I already see a pattern: For $n \ge 2$, $E(n)$'s denominator is a power of 6.  Now, can we find a formula for the numerator?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have found the pattern of numerator and got my answers. @Dan